# Get product image from Product Model Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am grabbing a product object with:

```
    $productId = 9184;
    $objectManagerProd = \Magento\Framework \App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $currentproduct = $objectManagerProd->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
```

I have tried to grab the product image with the image helper but it is not working. I have tried getImage() as well. Any body can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get product image from Product in PHTML file for Magento 2

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
<?php $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl(); ?>
```

Comment: You passed imageID value as "product_thumbnail_image". I have also seen "recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" inside magento. Can you please tell me how many types of imageID are there?

Answer (score 6):

try using imageHelper like following :

```
$objectManager  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helperImport   = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

    $imageUrl = $helperImport('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
        ->init($currentproduct, 'product_page_image_large')
        ->setImageFile($currentproduct->getFile())
        ->getUrl();
```

Comment: You don't use `$imagewidth` and `$imageheight`

Answer (score 0):

Try with Image Builder

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $product = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class)->load(5); //<Product ID>

    $image = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder::class);

    echo $image = $image->create($product, 'product_thumbnail_image', ['class' => 'photo image'])->toHtml();
```